# K8s loadbalance between different deployment/replicasets

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

we have a system that is having 2 endpoint based on geo-location. e.g (east_url, west_url).
One of our application need to load balance between those 2 urls. In the consumer application, created 2 deployment with the same image but different environment variables such as "url=east_url", "url=west_url".

after the deployment, i have following running pod, each of them will have label: "app=consumer-app" and "region=east" or "region=west"

- consumer-east-pod-1
- consumer-east-pod-2
- consumer-west-pod-1
- consumer-west-pod-2

when i create a clusterIP service with selector: app=consumer-app, somehow it only picks up one replicaSet. I am just curious if this is actually possible in kubernates to allow Service backed up by different deployments?

Another way of doing this i can think of is to create 2 services, and have ingress controller to loadbalance it, is this possible? we are using Kong as the ingress controller. I am looking for something like openshift which can have "alternativeBackends" to serve the Route. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/applications/deployments/route-based-deployment-strategies.html

Comment: You could also use 2 separate services, both backing the same ingress. This way traffic for east goes to the east pods and west goes to the west pods. If they are all using the same service, they will all receive traffic mixed together, so no geo-location

Comment: @PatrickW is that possible to create a k8s Service that is pointing to 2 url or ip, and also be able to define the liveness check on the endpoint?

Comment: You can have multiple URLs per ingress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a label for the east replicaSets, after i add the app:consumerAPP, it works fine now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**TL**;**DR**: use ***ISTIO***

With  [ISTIO](https://istio.io/) you can create [Virtual Services](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/):

> A **VirtualService** defines a set of traffic routing rules to apply when
>   a host is addressed. Each routing rule defines matching criteria for
>   traffic of a specific protocol. If the traffic is matched, then it is
>   sent to a named destination service (or subset/version of it) defined
>   in the registry.

The VirtualService will let you send traffic to different backends based on the URI.

Now, if you plan to perform like an *A/B TEST*, you can use ISTIO's (Destination Rule):[https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/].

> **DestinationRule** defines policies that apply to traffic intended for a
>   service after routing has occurred.
>
> Version specific policies can be specified by defining a named subset
>   and overriding the settings specified at the service level

1.- If you are using GKE, the process to install ISTIO can be located in [here](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview)

2.- If you are using K8s running on a Virtual Machine, the installation process can be found [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/)